# How do I connect a video camera to an Ubuntu laptop?

Tags: transfer

I have a Panasonic video camera and I want to download movies on my computer. What should I do?

Comment: What are your issues when you plug in your camera using the USB cable that probably came with your camera? Has your user permission to mount an external USB storage (group `plugdev`)?

Answer (score 1):

If the camcorder has a USB cable to connect to a computer, then in most cases plugging in the video camera to the computer running Ubuntu should make the video camera act similarly to a USB pen; Ubuntu should recognise that it has been plugged in and either open up the folder or give you a list of options (including open folder). Note that you may in some cases need to switch the camera on while it is plugged in or before it is plugged in to get it to work.

If this does not work, then Ubuntu may be struggling to mount the video camera. There are lots of [troubleshooting guides](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB) for this sort of issue. Just for reference, what model is the video camera?

Answer (score 0):

install `Cheese` to use your webcam to install cheese

- open your terminal
- Type
- `sudo apt-get install cheese`

  - Run Cheese. Cheese should automatically detect your webcam and display live video stream.

Hope that help helpful 
for more about webmca troubleshooting please see

[Ubuntu Community guide ( Webcam )](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam)

[Webcam Troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam/Troubleshooting)

Comment: Cheese will not help in copying files from the camera to the laptop.

Comment: I think there is some confusion here. I believe the Panasonic video camera refered to is not a webcam but rather a camcorder